# Is it possible to have multi-line in select option value

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-select

Is it possible to have multi-line in select option value

In the multi line option I would like show first line in bold and rest of lines in regular font.

---

[image]

---

Is there any possible approach using HTML/CSS and Java script or 
Do we have any library in React which can achieve the above

Comment: Not natively. You'd have to build your own custom control.

Comment: No, not with the built in `select/option`, and suggesting a tool or library is off topic. If your search the net you will find some options: https://www.google.com/search?q=multi-line+in+select+option+value&oq=multi-line+in+select+option+value&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You can't do it with a native HTML dropdown, but complex dropdowns are possible with divs and a styling library.  See https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#input for an example.

Comment: This might help http://jsfiddle.net/wdcrxzfb/

Comment: @Sheedo: Put that code into an answer, and include your Fiddle link.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried before adding it as a comment but it kept asking me to add code with it as well, and I don't know what to add...

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with current support of the `select` tag in current HTML version. The only possible solution here is to use a custom made solution, both vanilla CSS or javascript options are available, and you have plenty of techniques to choose from.

Whenever I found myself in a need of creating a custom solution I like to look for inspiration in this article:
https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index.html

Once you decide to go with custom made solution it is always a good practise to implement at least basic Screen Reader support.
A good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listbox_role#Best_practices

From my experience in business projects I usually prefer to go with JS powered solution, especially in such where frontend is changing a lot. My favourite here: https://select2.org/ which is both easy to customize and powerful enough to meet even the most challenging requirements, and you can't forget about really good docs.

As I can see you included a reactjs tag in your question, so if you are planning to create a react solution I would go with:
http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

which is pretty similar in functionality to Select2

Comment: "both vanilla CSS or javascript options are available": does the CSS or javascript has to be necessarily vanilla?

Comment: No offcourse not, Select2 in example is a jquery plugin.

Comment: I prefer to have a react plugin but I believe a multi-line option is not possible with react-select

Comment: It might not be available straight from the box, same as in the Select2, it requires some hacking, but despite that in every solution that provides you with a custom HTML structure, you can do with it almost everything, espesially in terms of styling.

You just need to overwrite some styles. Will you be getting your data from some sort of API or we are talking about hardcoded text here?

Comment: I think that I would start from concatening `userName` `userAddress` `userSchool` ( inside your React class ), in there you can easily control if you pass the naked values or some html markup with it as well. So imagine that you will pass a variable `userConcatened = <span>userName</span><span>userAddress</span><span>userSchool</span>` and the rest would be easily done with the CSS

Comment: Is still not possible with react-select as of today?